# Advantages in PL/SQL than T-SQL?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, plsql

Can we compare T-SQL & PL/SQL ? , how we define the differences between these  , and WHY its different ?  end of the day their scenario is Data definition and data manipulation :-S

Comment: It's different because Microsoft/Sybase and Oracle want to do things their way.

Comment: If you're looking for the key differences as a developer, this is one of my most popular blog entries, http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2007/04/24/oracle-plsql-equivalents-for-ms-sql-server-t-sql-constructs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different because they were written by two different sets of programmers. There is always more than one way to solve a problem. They go beyond the standard SQL because they are looking for something that either isn't in the standard and should have been, is a nice to have feature (that will sell more units) or they want something that will perform faster (performance is critical in Enterprise databases). They are trying to sell their product, so of course they want to make something that is enough different that it will be a selling point.

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL is from Oracle.  T-SQL is from Microsoft.  Both companies want to implement extras that make things easier for their developers, but since they are outside of the SQL standard they get new names.